# MVC4 dropdownlist selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have created a dropdownlist which shows timing with the gap of 1 hour on all days(mon-sun) the pre selected time from 9 am to 6 pm but i want to show holiday on sunday searched alot but find no help

here is my code

**Binding Dropdown**

```
public List<SelectListItem> StartTime()
 {
     List<SelectListItem> st = new List<SelectListItem>();
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "12:00 AM", Text = "12:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "01:00 AM", Text = "01:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "02:00 AM", Text = "02:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "03:00 AM", Text = "03:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "04:00 AM", Text = "04:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "05:00 AM", Text = "05:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "06:00 AM", Text = "06:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "07:00 AM", Text = "07:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "08:00 AM", Text = "08:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "09:00 AM", Text = "09:00 AM", Selected=true });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "10:00 AM", Text = "10:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "11:00 AM", Text = "11:00 AM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "12:00 PM", Text = "12:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "01:00 PM", Text = "01:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "02:00 PM", Text = "02:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "03:00 PM", Text = "03:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "04:00 PM", Text = "04:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "05:00 PM", Text = "05:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "06:00 PM", Text = "06:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "07:00 PM", Text = "07:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "08:00 PM", Text = "08:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "09:00 PM", Text = "09:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "10:00 PM", Text = "10:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "11:00 PM", Text = "11:00 PM" });
     st.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Holiday", Text = "Holiday" });
     return st;
 }
```

**View**

```
TimeFunctions tf = new TimeFunctions();
    List<SelectListItem> ST = tf.StartTime();
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MondayStart,ST)
```

now i want that when page loads then the dropdown for sunday is preselected wid Holiday

**updated**

i want the view like that

[image]

Comment: Then set `Selected` to true for the "Holiday" item instead? (or better yet set the data to "Holiday" on your model) I don't know what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @MohsinMustufa Ic is still correct...set the Holiday ``SelectListItem.Selected`` property to true on the sunday binding list.

Comment: @Kyle bro how to do that, that is what i am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give an ID to the dropdown list and then use jQuery to update it.

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MondayStart,ST, new { id = "SundayStartDropdown" })
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SundayStartDropdown').val('Holiday');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Are you using `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MondayStart,ST)` for each drop down list?

For the SundayStart and SundayEnd it should be using model.SundayStart or whatever the ID is for SelectedListItem with Value of "Holiday"

--

Try explicitly setting the selected value

```
dropdownlist.SlectedIndex = 9;
```

or

```
dropdownlist.SelectedValue = "Holiday";
```

Comment: Bro m using MVC not simple Asp.net

Comment: Problem solved
ive made the value of SundayStart and End to Holiday in `Controller` and then pass it to `Model`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

My Model:

```
namespace MVCMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Login
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User Name is required")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password is required")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string CountryList { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Country
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string SelectedCountry { get; set; }
        public Login()
        {
            Bindcountry();
        }

        public void Bindcountry()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> coutryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            coutryList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "India", Value = "India" });
            coutryList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "USA" });
            coutryList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "UK"});
            coutryList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mexico", Value = "Mexico" });
            coutryList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Germany", Value = "Germany", Selected = true });
            coutryList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "France", Value = "France" });


            this.Country = coutryList;
            SelectedCountry = "Mexico";

        }

    }
}
```

View :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryList, new SelectList(Model.Country,"Value","Text",Model.SelectedCountry))
```

This would give you the selected item in dropdown list